# Function pointers : *(void**) (&fun) = dlsym (lib, "fun") how its work?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, void-pointers, pointer-to-member, dlsym

I am using dlsym to populate of function pointer which is a member variable of call. 
like below

```
class ABC {
private: 
    void (*m_fun) (int);
}
```

now if I assign

```
m_fun = (void*) dlsym (libHandle, "fun")
```

It gives error

Over internet I found

```
*(void**) (&m_fun) = dlsym(libHandle, "fun") is working.
```

Can someone tell me how this conversion/casting happening here?

Comment: I don't want to use m_fun = (void*) (int) dlsym.....

Answer (score 4):

The cast says:

- take a pointer to a function
- get a pointer to that
- pretend that pointer points to a regular object pointer (`void*`) not a function pointer
- write the address returned by `dlsym` though that pointer, thereby setting the function pointer to that address

This works around the (usually desirable) restriction that you can't assign a function pointer to an object pointer. Since this is C++, you could write it as:

```
reinterpret_cast<void*&>(m_fun) = dlsym(libHandle, "fun");
```

which might be a bit clearer: pretend `m_fun` is a `void*`, and write to it.

Note that this is less portable than converting the result of `dlsym` to the correct type and assigning it:

```
m_fun = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int)>(dlsym(libHandle, "fun"));
```

which will either work correctly, or give a compiler error, on any platform. Your dodgier cast could cause undefined runtime behaviour on platforms with non-uniform memory architectures.

Comment: If function pointers and `void*` aren't mutually convertible, that platform probably won't have any `dlsym` implementation anyway.

Comment: @aschepler: Indeed. But the conversion could be non-trivial, in which case casting the assignment target rather than the result of `dlsym` might do the wrong thing

Comment: `dlsym` is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html), and POSIX requires conversion of `void*` to function pointer to work.

Comment: @larsmans: Indeed; but `*(void**)p = void_pointer` bypasses that conversion, so might do the wrong thing if the conversion is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Void* is just a memory pointer. To use function pointer to point to a function first a pointer towards the actual function and the rest of the pointer (**) is required to point towards the variables and the function body.